# How to achieve fileDetails part when query with GTLQueryYoutube on iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube-api

I am using GTLQueryYoutube to get list of uploaded videos. I actually login to my Google account. Using the following code to get uploaded videos

```
//Get my channel
GTLQueryYouTube *channelsListQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];

    channelsListQuery.mine = YES;

    youtubeService.APIKey = kGoogleClientAPIKey;

    // This callback uses the block syntax

    [youtubeService executeQuery:channelsListQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse*response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                //Process error later
                return;
            }

            if ([[response items] count] > 0) {
                //Get Uploaded ids
                GTLYouTubeChannel *channel = response[0];

                NSString *uploadsPlaylistId = channel.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

                GTLQueryYouTube *playlistItemsListQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];
                playlistItemsListQuery.maxResults = 20l;
                playlistItemsListQuery.playlistId = uploadsPlaylistId;
                playlistItemsListQuery.mine = YES;

                [youtubeService executeQuery:playlistItemsListQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            return;
                        }

                        NSMutableArray *videoIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:response.items.count];

                        for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in response.items) {

                            [videoIds addObject:playlistItem.contentDetails.videoId];

                        }

                        GTLQueryYouTube *videosListQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosListWithPart:@"id, contentDetails, snippet, **fileDetails**"];
                        videosListQuery.identifier = [videoIds componentsJoinedByString: @","];
                        videosListQuery.mine = YES;

                        [youtubeService executeQuery:videosListQuery

                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                if (error) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                NSArray* videoArray = response.items;

                                //Do somethings with videoArray


     }];
            }];
    }
}];
```

Consider the "videosListQuery" query, it has a part named "fileDetails" so each video returned on this query should be achieved the fileDetails property. But the result is on contrast, fileDetails property of each video is always nil

The fileDetails property can only be retrieve by owner, but I logined and it's my uploaded videos. Why can't I retrieve it?